# Count the number of times a jbutton is pressed?

Tags: java, count, jbutton

In the action performed code in a JAVA GUI, how would I count how many times a button is pressed. The final value of count variable should be stored even after the GUI window is closed and that value should be visible in the textfield where I get the count when the GUI is opened again.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem or just waiting for us to do the work?

Comment: Hint: You may need serialization or file concepts.

Comment: @PradeepSimha no need of `static` to accomplish this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hellow sir ..what is another way other then static..

Answer (score 1):

Below is the steps, which you may want to implemented in your code logic.

> 1. Maintain a counter instance variable, say `Integer count = 0;`
> 2. On each click, increase the count: `count++;`
> 3. On the window exit hook method (or panel unload), save count value on a persistent storage.

The persistence storage option could be one of the below:

- Write into a file ([Example here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42))
- Write to a database ([Example with Mysql](http://amilasurendra.info/writing-to-mysql-database-using-java/))
- Write to a serialized object ([Example here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57))

Answer (score 0):

### Part #1

I would start by creating a class that implements `ActionListener` and registering it with the button.

The only thing this class would do, is increment an internal counter each time `actionPerformed` is called.

### Part #2

This comes down to a number of possibilities.

You could use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) which is basically a key/value pair list (it's essentially a `HashMap` with some additional functionality) that would allow you to save and load it's contents.

The problem with this, is deals with `String` values, so you need to convert the value yourself.  The up-side, is you know where the file is saved and can modify it yourself should the need arise.

You could use the [`Preferences` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/).  It's a little more complicated the `Properties`, but deals with storing primitive values automatically.

The `Preferences` API also manages it store automatically, so you don't need to explicitly save or load it.  The drawback here is you don't know where these might be stored.